# If OpenVPN crashes or loses connection, can it revert silently to the default route?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have set up OpenVPN nd it is working. However, there is one thing I doubt:
On client machine, the routing after OpenVPN starts looks like this:

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0  proto dhcp  src 192.168.1.33  metric 1024 
10.8.0.1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0 
10.8.0.5 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.6 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5 dev tun0
```

If OpenVPN crashes or loses connection, can it revert silently to the default route, line number 2? This way, the client connection to generic Internet will be unprotected without warning. Can it happen? Do I need to write scripts to tear down old routes after VPN starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some research and found out I was right. It is indeed as I feared6 after VPN disconnection apllications silently revert to default route. To prevent this, I should use firewall.

[From Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenVPN#Prevent_leaks_if_vpn_goes_down):

```
# Default policies
 ufw default deny incoming
 ufw default deny outgoing

 # Openvpn interface (adjust interface accordingly to your configuration)
 ufw allow in on tun0
 ufw allow out on tun0

 # Local Network (adjust ip accordingly to your configuration)
 ufw allow in on enp3s0 from 192.168.1.0/24
 ufw allow out on enp3s0 to 192.168.1.0/24

 # Openvpn (adjust port accordingly to your configuration)
 ufw allow out on enp3s0 to any port 1194
 ufw allow in on enp3s0 from any port 1194
```

And if you need DNS to access your VPN server:

```
# DNS
 ufw allow in from any to any port 53
 ufw allow out from any to any port 53
```

Answer (score 0):

In all but the oddest of cases your vpn does actually use the default route to get the vpn endpoint. VPN is a typically implemented as a tunnel into a private network over external untrusted networks. It makes the traffic invisible.

When your VPN connection looses sync the tunnel might struggle for a few packets but ultimately is dropped at your end and your traffic will not get further than your end of the vpn tunnel, typically this will be some funky kind of network device. This should cause your application to software to raise an error , however this is a protocol specific as some will automatically attempt to resume over any available connection others are tied to specifics for security , performance or operational requirements.

Something to be careful about with VPN usage when you need to hide what you are doing is DNS , not all VPN solutions send the DNS queries via the VPN link, this is like giving a list of hosts you access to the owners of the DNS server or anyone who can sniff the traffic in between.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of struggle for nothing. OVPN.se gave me support.
The latest version for ubuntu is buggy.
With OVPN-linux-6-2.10.... I could login but not connect.
With the older version at
https://files.ovpn.com/client/new-updates/linux/ubuntu-qt6/2.11.0.6132/repo/OVPN-linux-6-2.11.0.6132.run I could login and connect.

When I accepted to update with the bugfix, OVPN behaved as before. The app appears, verifies and crash.

Ovpn.se should inform Ubuntu people about this and have them install the 2.11 version.
To get it running I must start OVPN in terminal in sudo mode.
cd /opt/OVPN and then
sudo ./OVPN